# My code will not write into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, reset

I have created a log in system and now I am trying to add reset password code to it. Everything seems to be working fine except it is not writing to the Mysql database. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$mycode = ($_POST['code']);
$mynewpass = ($_POST['password']);
$myconfpass = ($_POST['password1']);

    //checks if all fields are filled
if( (empty($mynewpass)) || (empty($myconfpass)) || (empty($mycode)) ){
    $errors[] = '<center>All fields must be filled in.<center>';
}   
    //check if passwords match
if ($mynewpass != $myconfpass){
    $errors[] = '<center>Your passwords do not match</center>'; 
}
        if (!empty($errors)){
    foreach($errors as $error){
        echo '<strong>',$error ,'</strong><br />';
    }
    }else{

include 'Grubconfig.php';

mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

// change password
$mychk = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer WHERE passreset = '$mycode' ");

if(mysql_num_rows($mychk) == 1)

     mysql_query("UPADTE customer SET Password='$mynewpass' WHERE passreset='$mycode'");
     mysql_query("UPADTE customer SET passreset='0' WHERE passreset='$mycode'");

    echo '<center>Your password has been reset Please click <a href="Grublogin.php">here !</a><center>';
    }
```

}
?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typos:

```
 mysql_query("UPADTE customer SET Password='$mynewpass' WHERE passreset='$mycode'");
              ^^^^^^--- UPDATE (swap D and A)
```

Never assume your queries were succesful. Always check for errors:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- bare minimum error handling
```

You are also wide open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). So you'd better read up about them and fix the holes before you deploy this code.

Comment: Thank you very much sometimes you need fresh eyes. I will look into SQL injection before i deploy. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($mychk) == 1)

 mysql_query("UPADTE customer SET Password='$mynewpass' WHERE passreset='$mycode'");
 mysql_query("UPADTE customer SET passreset='0' WHERE passreset='$mycode'");
```

1. UPDATE is spelled wrong
2. You don't have a a figure bracket open `if ( ... ) {`
   it's obligated, since you have 2 statements

You can stick them to one query:

```
UPDATE customer SET password = '$mynewpass', passreset = 0 WHERE passreset = '$mycode';
```

However, you'd better migrate your database interaction to either MySQLi or PDO. mysql library is now deprecated.